# simple login in php

Tags: php

I am new to php. I've created a simple user and password login form as follows:

```
if(isset($_POST['posted'])){

    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $pass= $_POST['pass'];

    if(!is_string($name))
    {
    echo "please enter name in alphabets";
    }
    else if($name=='muneeb' && $pass=='abcd')
    {
        header("location:1st.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "you entered wrong password";
    } }
```

But only one condition runs. I want to run all three.

Comment: How much combination you have tried? U:6 p:0; u:muneeb p:abcd; u:a p:b

Comment: Yes only one condition will run because anyof them satisfied then other will not get executed..

Comment: Drum roll - At what is the problem?

Comment: `is_string` doesn't check if characters are alphabetic, but if variable type is string. `"#@%^$#%#%$#"` is string for example. learn about [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php). you also have a lot more to learn about creating secure logins, but ok, you're at your beginings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['posted']))
    {

        $name= $_POST['name'];
        $pass= $_POST['pass'];

        if(is_numeric($name))
        {
            echo "please enter name in alphabets";
            exit;
        }

        if($name=='muneeb' && $pass=='abcd')
        {
            header("location:1st.php");
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "you entered wrong password";
            exit;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: `is_numeric`? no, unless you want `%^$#@%$^` to be valid username, which is not what he wants. learn about [`ctype_alpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alpha.php)

Answer (score 0):

Following Marko D's comment on my post here the edit.

Note that $name and $pass have no empty checks, consider using a simple if(empty) to check for empty field and output an error message.

About the is_numeric, Marko D's is right, it applies only for numbers, not for specials chars, following up on his suggestion, here an example how to use ctype_alpha.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
if (!ctype_alpha($name)) {
   echo('Your name may include letters only');
} else {
   // proceed to function
}
```

Comment: stop copy/pasting code. analyze it instead, and realize that `is_numeric` is completely wrong. assigning variables from post without checking if they exist is also wrong. if you mention `ob_start` then you owe him a longer explanation as to why, and if something else is neccessary.

Comment: I looked over it, I'm sorry :)

Comment: that's because you're creating separate if statements, consider doing the following: